# How to copy on xclip and see the command output on the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, pipe, xclip

Whenever I use xclip the command output goes right the clipboard but I also need to see it on the terminal:

I already tried this commands using pipe and & `|&`:

```sh
pwd |& xclip -rmlastnl -selection clipboard
```

but doesn't work (the output goes right to the clipboard but I don't see it on the terminal).

the expected result is symple, whenever I do this:

```sh
pwd | xclip
```

I should get both the output on the shell:

> path/working/directory

and also the same result on my clipboard.

Comment: `ls | xclip | xclip -o`

Comment: thanks! This give me the hint to find the solution, I will explain more below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @raminnietzsche I found the solution:

Since I'm using KDE I needed to send the copy strings to the default clipboard. So I achieved this with this command:

`xclip -rmlastnl -selection clipboard`

Since the copied strings goes to the main clipboard, the same options should be used when we use xclip -o. So the code to achieve what I wanted should be this one:

```
pwd | xclip -rmlastnl -selection clipboard | xclip -o -rmlastnl -selection clipboard
```

The problem is that with pipe the commands seems to run simultaneously, so the paste content (with `xclip -o` etc...) will be the one already stored and not the new one. In other words it will copy the command output but will paste the last copied content.

To solve this I used `&&` instead of the second `|` in order to paste only after the copy happens.

I also created some alias on my zsh (or bash) config for the sake of time and clarity:

```
alias copy="xclip -rmlastnl -selection clipboard"
alias past="xclip -o -rmlastnl -selection clipboard"
```

**So the working command is**:

```
pwd | copy && past
```